# Python recursive function that reverses a list

Tags: python, function, recursion

[Picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XPZn.jpg)

I want to write a recursive function that reverses a list.
Given an input: [1,2,3], the function should return [3,2,1]

I am however recieving this error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wbUY.jpg)

Comment: Please include your code and error as code blocks, not as images. No one can bother re-typing code from an image to help you.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
def reverse(lst,start,end):
      if start>=end:
         return lst
      else:
        temp=lst[start]
        lst[start]=lst[end]
        lst[end]=temp
        return reverse(lst,start+1,end-1)

l = [1,2,3]
print(reverse(l,0,len(l)-1))
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for any recursive programming:

```
list_in = [1, 2, 3]
list_out = list_in[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`newList.append(temp)` doesn't have a return value, and therefore returns None. `newList.append(temp)` adds temp to newList, so your code could work as:

```
def recursiveReverse(dataList):
    if len(dataList) == 1:
        return dataList
    else:
        temp = dataList.pop(0)
        newList = recursiveReverse(dataList)
        newList.append(temp)
        return newList
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the error message it is throwing an error is you are trying to append something to none type as in the line `return yourlist.append(element)`.
Try appending to the list first and then return it.
Like

```
mylist.append(element)
return mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, lists are mutable objects, and `list.append` adds an element to the existing list but doesn't return anything. That's why you're getting that error.